# access methods on one socketio namespace from a different one

Tags: python, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I have a flask application that uses flask-socketio and python-socketio to facilitate communication between a socketio server in the cloud and a display device via a hardware device.

I have a **display** namespace which exposes the display facing events, and also uses a separate **client** class which connects and talks to the server in the cloud. This works well as designed, but now I want to trigger the connection method in my **client** class from a different namespace. So far I have not been able to get this to work.

What I have tried is adding the **display** namespace class to the flask context, then passing that into the socketio.on_namespace() method. Then from the other namespace I am grabbing it from current_app and trying to trigger the connection to the cloud server. This returns a 'RuntimeError: working outside of application context' error.

So at this point I'm still researching how to do this correctly, but I was hoping someone has dealt with something like this before, and knows how to access methods on one namespace from a different one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of instantiating my **client** class from the **display** namespace, I instantiate it before I add the namespaces to socketio. Then I pass the client object into both namespaces when I call the socketio.on_namespace() method.